Is the Higgs Boson missing from ParticleData?
WolframAlpha seems to know about the Higgs Boson, lists all the properties like decay modes, mass, etc. in detail, and refers to the Wolfram code:
Entity["Particle", "HiggsBoson"]
When I run this in a cell Mathematica 13.0.1.0
In[1]:= Entity["Particle", "HiggsBoson"]
It returns a general Entity "HiggsBoson" with dropdown properties (mass, charge, etc.).  When I try and access those dropdown properties, it returns errors like
"the HiggsBoson is not a known entity, class, or tag for ParticleData".
When I enter in a cell
ParticleData["HiggsBoson"]
I get the same error (other particles work fine).
Any insights into this behavior?  The Higgs isn't exactly obscure or new (and given ParticleData has far more obscure particles in it), why is the Higgs Boson missing from ParticleData but yet fully present in WolframAlpha?

Entity works for me in V14.0, but ParticleData["HiggsBoson"] does not ...

The reason may be that ParticleData seems to get is source by default from outdated particle data circa 2009 before the Higgs was discovered while WolframAlpha appears up to date (also using Wolfram|Alpha Knowledge base, 2020).
